# How to call onchange function in window.onload from javascript

Tags: javascript, select, window.open, box

I'm developing web page by using javascript and I have a question.

Everybody knows we use `window.onload()` function for initial status.

In my source code, Select box have `onchange="onChangeServer()"` function plus `<input type="text">`.

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="server_name" class="form-control" onchange="onChangeServer()" onselect="">
      <option value="0">A Server</option>
      <option value="1">B Server</option>
      <option value="2">C Server</option>
      <option value="3">etc</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input id="server_name_input" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

If `onChangeServer()` function is changed, `<input>` tag will be writed about server information.

How to call `onChangeServer()` function in `window.onload()`?

Thanks~!

Comment: Oh... my god... I resolved.. ㅠㅠ

I added "window.onload = onChangeServer();"... I'm so sorry~!

Comment: Please post a properly formatted answer to your own question if you have one.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I add resolved source.

Comment: No. If you realised a solution to your own question, you should post the solution as an answer (below), not add it to the question (above). Now your question contains the solution, it isn't a question.

Comment: Yes. I understand! I'll write it now!

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue.

I'm just add "window.onload = onChangeServer();"

This line mean "Call onChangeServer() function. When you want to call some function as soon as page is onload"

```js
window.onload = onChangeServer();

function onChangeServer(){
 var selsvr = document.getElementById("server_name");
 var servername = selsvr.options[selsvr.selectedIndex].value;

 var tempServerName = null;
 if(servername=="0"){
  tempServerName = server_0;
 } else if(servername=="1"){
  tempServerName = server_1;
 } else if(servername=="2"){

 } else if(servername=="3"){

 } else {

 }
 serverNameInput.value = tempServerName;
}
```

Thanks a lot~